# companyField was not showing as link in ListView in Lightning Experiance

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

Images for Classic and Lightning...[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I dont think it will work in Lightning expererience

Comment: is there any solution to it?

Comment: No idea @user55726

Comment: In Classic, is link for Company (a text field) taking you to the Account page or is it taking you to same page as Lead Name?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own Formula field and then have it render a HYPERLINK. Would look something like this:

HYPERLINK("/{!Lead.Id}","{!Lead.Company}")

This would create a field that displays company and then links back to the lead then add this to your lead list views.